# Using psql command line within powershell - and formatting the output

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I'm using this command within a powershell script to extract a single value into a file

```
.\psql -U myowner -d myDB -c "SELECT last_value FROM pg_sequences WHERE sequencename ='mytest'" -o c:\test.dat
```

This works OK, and dumps the output to test.dat as follows

```
 last_value
-------------
 13446137112
(1 row)
```

How do I loose the column header and the footer? I just want the value alone, no bumpf. i.e. just a file containing

```
 13446137112
```

I could probably hack something with powershell, but was hoping for a more elegant formatting option within `psql`

(psql v13.1, powershell v5.1, windows 11)

UPDATE - Abdul Azizs' answer is correct (thank-you). '-t' strips out the header and footer. Bonus points for striping off the leading spaces and extra blank lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in the `-t` / `--tuples-only` flag to enable tuples-only, this suppresses the column names and footers.

```
.\psql -U myowner -d myDB -t -c "SELECT last_value FROM pg_sequences WHERE sequencename ='mytest'" -o c:\test.dat
```

With the `-t` option, psql will output only the tuple data without the column header and footer.

Check out [PostgreSQL's app-psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for more info.